# Andorid studio cannot run in my android device

Tags: android, android-studio

I am tring to run my `android studio`'s program in my android device (`Asus ZenFone GO`).
But in device chooser window I cannot found my device instead there is an "**Emulator unknown emulator-5678 [OFFLINE]**" like following printscreen:

[image]

I think my device driver was installed correctly. Here is my device manager printscreen:

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Are you running it for the first time? Have you enabled the developer mode in your phone

Comment: my phone was in developer mode. yes, this is the first time

Comment: Have you checked the `USB debuging` in the developer options settings in your phone. Btw what is your android Os.. its saying it is not compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you have enabled `Developer options` in your device. You can enable it by tapping several times on `Build number` of your device (`Settings > About phone > Build number`). After doing that, you need to enable `USB debugging`. For more details visit [Using Hardware Devices](http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html).

Answer (score 0):

I also do testing in Asus Zenfon and This was helpful for me:

1. Disconnect mobile.
2. Build an app again
3. Connect mobile

I want to clarify that this is not a device specific problem.

Comment: Thanks. i did that, the problem is my USB debugging was disabled